# Want to use browserAction and pageAction at the same time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Documentation says we can have only browserAction or pageAction not both. Is there any trick for this? Or as solution is this good idea to use content script and insert button in a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no mechanism for a single extension to have more than one UI element in Chrome's chrome. You could certainly inject code into a page, and present some UI there, but you won't be able to have both a `browserAction` and `pageAction` in a single extension.

You could, on the other hand, have *two* extensions which communicate with each other via message passing. See [`chrome.extension.sendRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/extension.html#method-sendRequest) for details as to how that might work.

Comment: Also if you've got a browserAction you can have a background page that monitors tabs and changes the browserActions icon according to what page your on.